# How to keep the image in inside the div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place an image on my site. But the image is crossing the div border and going out and thus making the website horizontally scrollable.

I have use the float tag in css.

here is my css code

```css
.image-2{
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;

}
```

my did style sheet

```css
.about{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #130178, #4F35DF, #5FD0F5);
}
```

How can I keep the image fixed inside the div and stop it from going out and increasing the width of the site?

Comment: Can you add html code?

Comment: Here is the html code https://pastecode.xyz/view/6bacaec4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max-height:100%; max-width:100%; object-fit: contain;` for the image inside the div.

Comment: `max-height` and `max-width` for the main div or the image div?

Comment: For the image within the div. Ex from your HTML `<img id = "img1" src="asset/image/banner-1.png">`. Then your CSS  `#img1{max-height:100%; max-width:100%; object-fit: contain; }`.

Comment: No problem!! :)

Comment: sure! I just did.

Answer (score 0):

add width: 100%;to the image. then image inside parent element